# C++ Win32 Wininet Causing Lags or My Code?

Tags: c++, windows

I made a program using Code::Blocks and compiled it with GNU GCC Compiler. When i click a button really fast i get a really bad lag, i dont know if its because of my code or if its because im using Cases for each button. Of my bad way of using string streams and string to do my string concentration im still new to this but it works, If anyone knows it will help alot thanks. it

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            /*
             * TODO: Add more control ID's, when needed.
             */
            case Create:
            {
                GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, GuildN, Readuni, sizeof(Readuni));
                GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, PWN, Readpw, sizeof(Readpw));
                GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, Namen, Readnamec, sizeof(Readnamec));
                GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, souln, Readsoulc, sizeof(Readsoulc));
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "uniform=" << Readuni << "&pw=" << Readpw;
                std::string sss = ss.str();
                char frmdata[1000] ;
                for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
                frmdata[i]=sss[i];
                std::stringstream ssurl;
                ssurl << "/cgi-bin/myCGI/sr-guilds.cgi/WOS/create/0/" << Readsoulc << "." << Readnamec << "/31321/00000000";
                std::string url = ssurl.str();
                //std::string url("/cgi-bin/myCGI/sr-guilds.cgi/WOS/create/0/00000001.Samsyn/31321/00000000");
                hSession = InternetOpen("wosPost",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
                hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, "207.57.118.86",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
                hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST", url.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
                HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
                InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
                InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
                InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
                r

eturn TRUE;
                }
case joinr:
            {
                    GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, guildj, Readguildj, sizeof(Readguildj));
                    GetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, namej, Readnamej, sizeof(Readnamej));
                    std::string fill = "00000";
                    int randomValue = rand() %899 + 100;
                    std::stringstream ss;
                    ss << "desc=Level 100 Emperor (Sword-User) age 80:23 (Evergreen) (PKer)&stat=Kills:4085, PKs:2503, Deaths:15, PKed:2830, Rating: 800&name=" << fill << randomValue << "." << Readnamej;
                    std::string sss = ss.str();
                    char frmdata[1500] ;
                    for(int i=0;i<1500;i++)
                    frmdata[i]=sss[i];
                    std::stringstream ssurl;
                    ssurl << "/cgi-bin/myCGI/sr-guilds.cgi/WOS/petition/" << Readguildj << "/" << Readnamej << "." << fill << randomValue << "/31321/00000000";
                    std::string url = ssurl.str();
                    //std::string url("/cgi-bin/myCGI/sr-guilds.cgi/WOS/create/0/00000001.Samsyn/31321/00000000");
                    hSession = InternetOpen("wosPost",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
                    hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, "207.57.118.86",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
                    hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST", url.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
                    HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
                    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
                    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
                    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
                    return TRUE;
                    }
```

Here is basically the same code coded with QT that does not lag.

```
void MainWindow::on_Join2_clicked()
{
    QString Fill = "00000";
    int randomValue = rand() %899 + 100;
    QString inttostr;
    inttostr.append(QString("%1").arg(randomValue));
    QString guildslot = ui->GuildJ->text();
    QString NamexJ = ui->NameJ->text();
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://synthetic-reality.com/cgi-bin/myCGI/sr-guilds.cgi/WOS/petition/" + guildslot + "/" + Fill + inttostr + "." + NamexJ + "/31321/00000000"));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "wosPost");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    QByteArray content = "";
    content += "desc=Level 100 Emperor (Sword-User) age 80:23 (Evergreen) (PKer)&";
    content += "stat=Kills:4085, PKs:2503, Deaths:15, PKed:2830, Rating: 800&";
    content += "name=" + Fill + inttostr + "." + NamexJ;
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(request), content);

}
```

Comment: You'd have to profile to be sure, but I'm guessing those web requests are pretty expensive

Comment: sorry i had the wrong code posted its Joinr that i want to make it faster, i had this all working good on QT and im trying to compile it in just c++ without qt. using Wininet, would string steams and then a for loop make it perform slow?? QT uses some voids to know when a button is pressed. void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() i wonder if those perform faster.

Comment: @Tprice88: You're apparently establishing a connection over the Internet every time you press a button. Of course it'll lag, connecting over the Internet isn't exactly what you call fast, relatively speaking.

Comment: Do you think i would have to use something different then Wininet.H, the same thing does not cause a lag with QT.

Comment: Naturally the QT version will be faster because you aren't waiting for the post to report `isFinished()`. You can get the same effect with wininet by passing `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC` to `InternetOpen`.

Comment: where would i put INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC at

Comment: is their another one its not sending my post data with this - hSession = InternetOpen("wosPost",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);

Comment: Probably because you are closing the handle before the operation completes.

Comment: Yah u are Right u should of submited that as a answer, Its working now but not all of my post data is getting sent right, so i might look into another libary to compile this with.